# Why does Ruby sometimes throw an error when a function is called with a space before the parentheses?

Tags: ruby, function, syntax, parentheses

The way I've learned Ruby is that both function syntax with and without parentheses is acceptable. Why do some Ruby interpreters want specifically one over the other?

```
def foo(i)
    puts "=" * i.length
    puts i 
    puts "=" * i.length
end

foo "hello" 

=begin
=====
hello
=====
=end

foo ("hello") 
# sometimes ERROR
```

Comment: I don't know of any Ruby that would complain about that. Parentheses are completely optional for non-ambiguous arguments. Do you mean "interpreters" as in Ruby  vs. JRuby, or do you mean "interpreter" as in linters like [Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: I'm not talking about JRuby, I made a false assumption, thinking there are many common Ruby interpreters the same way there are many common C compilers. To be clear, sometimes it complains about the space, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Ruby 2.6.3 I get the following warning when run with `ruby -w`.

> test.rb:1: warning: parentheses after method name is interpreted as an argument list, not a decomposed argument

This is referring to [Array Decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) where you can unpack the elements of an Array argument into individual variables.

```
def bar((a,b))
  puts "a: #{a}, b: #{b}"
end

# a: first, b: second
bar ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

What's wrong with `def foo (i)`? `def foo i` is legal; [parenthesis around the arguments are optional](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments). However `def foo (i)` is ambiguous. It can be interpreted as a single argument `def foo(i)` or an array decomposition `def foo((i))`.

Because this is ambiguous, different interpreters may have different... interpretations.

Comment: And I had no idea about any of this until I researched the question.

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri I've never seen any Ruby code leave out the parens in function arguments nor use array decomposition. I expect it's a piece of early syntax that got tossed into the dustbin and left in for backwards compatibility. Some old programming styles like to put a space between everything like `func (args)` which is legal but not used in Ruby. These are syntax edge cases I'd recommend you avoid, they welcome ambiguity. No parens when calling a method is fine.

Comment: Are you sure it is the parentheses and not the spacing? `def m(x)` is not ambiguous but `def m (x)` could be. Just like `m(1,2)` is valid but `m (1,2)` is a syntax error. You example points to this but it isn't explicit.

Comment: @muistooshort It's both. `def foo i`, no parens, not ambiguous. `def foo(i)`, no space, not ambiguous. `def foo (i)`, both a space and parens, ambiguous. Does it mean `def foo(i)` (an extra space between the function name and the argument list) or `def foo((i))` (no parenthesis around the argument list which includes an array decomposition)? Ruby 2.6.2 chooses to interpret it as the former, probably because array decomposition is never used but some styles like to put spaces between every token.

Comment: do you mean like the ES6 equivalent "object destructuring" when you say "array decomposition"?

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri Similar idea. Treat `foo([1,2,3])` as `foo(1,2,3)`. There's a link to the Ruby docs on the subject in the answer.